# function returns true false or maybe

Tags: php

I have a function that returns true or false based on its algorithm and works fine.

```
function abc(){
    if(somecondition){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and later on in my code I do

```
if(abc()){
    //code if the function returns true
}else{
    //code if the function returns false
}
```

and this works flawlessy.

Now I want to handle a situation where the function should return a "maybe" status so that later on I perform an additional check. So my pseudo code becomes:

```
function abc(){
    if(somecondition){
        return true;
    }elseif(someothercondition){
        return 'maybe';
    }else{
        return false;
}
```

and later on in my code I do

```
if(abc()){
    //code if the function returns true
}elseif(abc()=='maybe'){
    //code if the function returns maybe
}else{
    //code if the function returns false
}
```

Is this going to work? Is this the correct way to handle this?. I am asking since the maybe condition is a very remote situation in my code that is hard to replicate and this makes it hard for me to test directly

Comment: `if(abc())` would yield true, when the return value is `maybe`. You would at least need to start with a type-safe comparison with `true` here.

Comment: @CBroe so instead of if(abc()) I need to do if(abc()==true)? because returning a value is a situation where the function is returning "not false", correct?

Comment: To make things a bit clearer, I'd create an enumerator class for the function to return and then test its value. Though it sounds like your edge case could be an exception, which you could try and handle here.

Comment: No, you'd need the triple equal, aka "identical". Try to dump the value of `'maybe' == true`.

Comment: If `abc()` has side effects, calling it twice might be problematic. Also having a function that returns a boolean or a string, whereas the string must be inspected to know it's meaning is just bad (IMO). Better return a value object (or enum or anything with a clear api).

Comment: the edge case is if the php session has expired and there is a specific cookie with username. In that case I ask the user just to put in the password and not username and password. This to handle the situation when the user leaves the browser open for long time, the session expires and so he has to login again

Comment: Then I think an enum would be the way to go.

Comment: @El_Vanja what do you mean with "enumerator"? like true becomes a string 'loggedin', false 'notLoggedin' and 'maybe' in the third situation?

Comment: An enumerator would be a class which would hold values such as the ones you suggested. But since you're using procedural style, I believe Petr's answer would fit your code best.

Comment: From my POV, the "correct" way would be to have a **reliable** return value, either `true`  or `false`

Comment: @NicoHaase Sometimes you just need a third state and a boolean simply isn't sufficient.

Comment: "is this going to work?" have you run it to see?

Comment: @TylerH yes. And I have added a second question: is this the correct way to handle this situation? Is it going to work means if this is solution is solid enough to be put in production code. It works in an happy path obviously but this was not sufficient when I asked this question

Comment: @LelioFaieta If it runs, then it is correct. If you have a specific, *objective* question or concern, rephrase to ask about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a cleaner approach to return `nullable bool`, than `mixed`.

So your implementation would be

```
function abc(): ?bool
{
    if (somecondition) {
        return true;
    } elseif (someothercondition) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Where the `null` value stands for "maybe".

You'll also need to use [strict comparison](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (`===`). In loose comparison (`==`) `null` would equal to `false`.

```
$abc = abc();

if ($abc === false) {
   // no
} elseif ($abc === null) {
   // maybe
}
```

Comment: This solution looks good because OP seems to be looking for a tristate value.

Comment: Definitely the simplest approach for procedural style.

Comment: (The cons is that null value is related to maybe, which is not a semantic value that one would first think of, but whatever, this is a workaround to deal with a lack of the language, enums.)

Comment: One nitpicky detail though; you don't need an `if-elseif` construction when returning. Two independent `if`s and a "default" return would suffice.

Comment: I agree with the answer and the comments. This three states with null is good to go. Thanks all for the effort

Answer (score 2):

The condition after return evaluates to either true or false, so there's no need for the if/else.

```php
function abc(){
    /*if(somecondition){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }*/
    return somecondition;
}
```

or

```php
function abc(){
    /*if(somecondition){
        return true;
    }elseif(someothercondition){
        return 'maybe';
    }else{
        return false;
    }*/
    return someothercondition ? 'maybe' : somecondition;
}
```

the condition the more specific should be the first to evaluate abc()=='maybe'.
so change this

```php
if(abc()){
    //code if the function returns true
}elseif(abc()=='maybe'){
    //code if the function returns maybe
}else{
    //code if the function returns false
}
```

to that to be more specific

```php
if(abc()==='maybe'){
    //code if the function returns maybe
}elseif(abc()){
    //code if the function returns true
}else{
    //code if the function returns false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is the correct answer to my question but the solution I finally implemented is taking input from a comment by @nicohaase. I splitted in two the function so that the code becomes:

```
function abc(){
    if(somecondition){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function def(){
    if(someothercondition){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

then I do:

```
if(abc()){
    //do something
}else{
    //this is false, check other conditions
    if(def()){
        //do something else
    }else{
        //execute code if all return false
    }
}
```

I have moved the "maybe" outside the function so the functions return a boolean as expected and the code is cleaner to read.